# C Name Mangling - Where are the technical documents?

Tags: c, gcc, specifications, symbols

The C standard does not specify how compilers should generate the name of a C function inside an object file. It seems that GCC compatible front-ends simply prepend the name of the C function by an underscore. Microsoft compilers use a different strategy.

However, a lot of languages are able to call C functions (Rust, Go, etc). 
I assume that the developers had access to some document explaining how the C symbols are translated by the different compilers on the different operating systems.

Is there some publicly available website/document/RFC documenting this point for the different compilers (GCC, Visual C++, etc) or operating systems?

**EDIT:** On this page http://www.iecc.com/linker/linker05.html in the *Name Mangling* section, a brief history is given. On this post: [What is the reason function names are prefixed with an underscore by the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908568/what-is-the-reason-function-names-are-prefixed-with-an-underscore-by-the-compile/5908708#5908708), we talk about a simple convention. Has this rule been ever written somwhere in some of the compilers' documentation?

Comment: What different Microsoft strategy do you mean? When compiling as C code, MS uses simple preceding underscores like everyone else.

Comment: It's part of [the ***ABI***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I read somewhere that MS uses the name uses an underscore prefix and on 32 bits architecture adds an `@` followed by the size of arguments in bytes. @some-programmer-dude, is there any explicit ABI document somewhere?

Comment: note/understand that one "brand" of compiler doesnt always do it the same way or historically has not, some have command line options to manipulate is there a leading underscore or not.  When trying to mix and link languages you just have to do the work.  and re-do the work if you change compilers/tools on either side.  Or use assembly as your middle language to combine the two.

Comment: Well, there you're talking about C++, not C.

Comment: Nope, I speak about C not C++ mangling.

Comment: It is platform/compiler specific. You have to find the rules used in the platform. There is no standard source of the information. The standard doesn’t pontificate on the issue (nor should it).

Comment: Yes. Precisly! I wanted some help to find out those documents for some compilers. For GCC, I failed to find :(

Comment: @yageek: gcc is a *compiler* (more accurately, a collection of compilers) which produces code gor various platforms. You need to search for ABIs per platform. There are a couple of links at the end of the first section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325157/calling-c-function-which-takes-no-parameters-with-parameters/31325626).

Comment: @rici Thanks for the link :) But I guess the API precises how the parameters are pushed on the stack and so on and does not precise how C compilers should mangle the name of the C function inside ELF object right?

Comment: The abi also defines names. So not right.

Comment: I took a look on the mentioned documents and they does not seem to speak about mangling of C functions. :(

Comment: @yageek - Nowhere does the C standard say anything about ELF formats. C compilers are free to use [other formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx)